# There is a way to randomly shuffle a keras layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to add as first layer on a keras NN (functional mode), a random shuffle of the 1D input data.

Is that possible? If not possible, a random translation would be second best.

I found that keras implements  [keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomTranslation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/RandomTranslation)

but is for 4D data, and my data is 1D

If a NN is needed for the question, I want to random shuffle the input  of [this toy network](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/257653/239384).

I tried to preprocess the input with

```
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(input_shape)
    randomTranslation=keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomTranslation(\
        height_factor=1, width_factor=1, fill_mode='wrap',\
        interpolation='nearest', seed=None, name=None)

    input_layer=randomTranslation(input_layer)
```

But I get the error "Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 3"

Tensorflow implements [tf.random.shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/shuffle), but I don't know if it can be turned into a keras layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn almost any TF function into a lyaer. For functional models and your case, suppose that your input is `input`. Then you can do the following:

```
input_transposed = tf.transpose(input, perm=[1,0])
input_shuffled_transposed = tf.random.shuffle(input_transposed)
input_shuffled = tf.transpose(input_shuffled_transposed, perm=[1,0])
```

The first command is needed as `tf.random.shuffle` shufles along the first dimension. In training time, this would be the batch dimension. To shuffle the data and not the samples in the batch, one can simple use `tf.transpose` to "rename" the axis.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have to figure which approach is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can come up with is this abomination:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.reshape(tf.range(1, 11), (2, 5))

inputlayer = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,))
out = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.map_fn(lambda y:
    tf.random.shuffle(y), x))(inputlayer)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputlayer, out)

model(inp)
```

From this:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 5), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])>
```

To this:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 4.,  1.,  5.,  3.,  2.],
       [10.,  6.,  9.,  8.,  7.]], dtype=float32)>
```